# Excel Macro to read multiple files in a folder and search in it

Tags: vba, excel

I have some excel workbooks of same header rows. I need to search in a particular column in all these workbooks and do a countif kind of functionality in a corresponding column( different than the first column)
For eg.. Column  A has names of boxes, B has information about the contents in each box. I would like to search multiple excels in folder and get a report of unique box names and their content counts. Box A has 5 apples, 2 oranges , 1 mango.

I hope this requirement is clear enough. Could anyone help me with a base axcel macro code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This isn't really a place for learning the basics about coding -- more of a site to bring a question about a _specific_ programming issue you're having, sharing your code so far to show that an effort has been made.  Check out the [tour] as well as the [topic faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [mcve].  You can [edit] your question to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Talking about workbooks you have different files (*.xls) in one folder? Then you can start with something like this:

```
Dim Path As Integer
Path = "Type in the path with your workbooks"

File = Dir$(Path & "\*.xls")
Do While File <> ""
    'Do stuff like:
    'opening your workbook and search for the names of the boxes
    'save your needed informations in a variable or array
    'close the workbook
    File = Dir$()
Loop
```

Or do you mean you have one workbook (one file) with more worksheets? Then do something like this:

```
Dim i
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    'Do your stuff here
Next i
```

If you want to get better help please post some of your code with specific questions